# use elasticsearch for statistics

Tags: database, elasticsearch

Can i use elasticsearch to store statistic informations with less overhead?
It should be used for example how often is a function call was made
and how much time has it taken.
Or how many requests has been made to a specific endpoint and also the time it has taken, and so on.
My idea would be to store a key, timestamp and takenTime.
And i can query results in different manner.
simply handled by functions like profile_start and profile_done

```
void endpointGetUserInformation()
{
  profile_start("requests.GetUserInformation");
  ...
  // profile_done stores to the database
  profile_done("requests.GetUserInformation");
}
```

In a normal sql database i would make a table witch holds all keys, and a second table that holds key_ids, timestamp and timeTaken. This storage would need less space on disk.

When i store to elasticsearch it stores a lot of data additionally and also the key is redundant is there a solutuion to store it also simplier.

Comment: You are asking if Elastic can be used as a time series database, the short answer to which is "yes". There are other time series databases available and I would suggest you do some research around the merits of each. 

In your question you mention a relational table would take less space than Elastic for the same data... How did you reach this conclusion? Elastic does store some meta information with each document such as version and doc id, but a relational database is going to be storing similar information about row data.

Comment: I would suggest that you spin up an Elastic instance and index some data... I think you'll struggle to present it well with a relational database, with Elastic or another time series db you will find this much easier. Maybe look at InfluxDb and Grafana as a presentation layer.